FFmpeg fps detection bug?
I have ffmpeg setup which produces rtmp stream from remote rtsp stream. The rtsp stream comes from ip camera which support multiple profiles. Each profile has 1080p 30 fps, 1080p 15 fps.
The weird thing is that when ffmpeg analyze its input stream, one profile is recognized as 1 fps as below
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://...':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    comment         : samsung
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.064144, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1 fps, 1 tbr, 90k tbn, 2 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Data: none
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp:...':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    comment         : samsung
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 1k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)

And when it is played the tbr is 30 i think it means the real fps from video stream is 30.
The other stream is normal 30 fps input 30 fps. I want to know what cause this fps detection bug?
